# How to get exact value without rounding off

Tags: java

Using java I need to calculate the value for 1/(2^50)

I am getting value as 0.0000000000000008881784197001252

But the exact value is
0.00000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625

I used power function and divison operator.

Comment: You can use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Downvoted because there is plenty of topics covering that issue.

Comment: Learn how to use the Java API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 0):

you could use the NumberFormat and doing the following:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(); 
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(5);
System.out.println(nf.format(VariableHere));
```

this would set the number to have a minimum of 0 decimal places and a maximum of 5 and then print out the re-formatted number.

Answer (score 0):

Very close to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23866888/divide-big-integer-number-to-get-exact-value) question

```
    BigDecimal bi1 = new BigDecimal("2").pow(50);
    BigDecimal bi2 = BigDecimal.ONE;

    BigDecimal bi3 = bi2.divide(bi1);
    System.out.println(bi3);
```

gives output `8.8817841970012523233890533447265625E-16`

but if you wont avoid this notation and get pure digits you can add

```
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(100);
    System.out.println(nf.format(bi3));
```

and it will give an exact output `0,00000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625`

Comment: String s = bi3.toPlainString();
System.out.println(s);
This will give the exact output...