# Divide big integer number to get exact value

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to find the value of **1/(2^n)** where **0 <=n<= 200**

I have tried to use biginteger but it is giving output as zero . I want exact number after division .

```
import java.math.BigInteger;


public class Problem2 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        BigInteger bi1 =  new BigInteger("2").pow(200);
        BigInteger bi2 =    BigInteger.ONE;

         BigInteger bi3 = bi2.divide(bi1);
         System.out.println(bi3);  //why it giving output zero
    }
}
```

On  use of BigDecimal it is giving exponential value , but how to get exact value without exponent.

Comment: `1/2^n` is unlikely to be an integer for `n > 0`.. Use `BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: This is an Integer not an BigDecimal.

Comment: The usual solution when you want to work with exact fractions is to actually work with exact fractions. That is, don't even do the division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because 0< bi3 <1, so an integer result is 0. Try `BigDecimal` in place of `BigInteger`

Comment: but my question is how to get exact value . ?

Comment: but on use of Big Decimal it is giving exponential value. For example on n= 100 it is giving output as 7.888609052210118054117285652827862296732064351090230047702789306640625E-31

Comment: It is an exponential display of a value, not exponential value. The value is the same. To have the display that you want `bi3 .toPlainString()`

Answer (score 3):

BigInteger works like Integer in that the result of calculations between two integers is an integer.

If we write int `n = 1 / 1024` the result is likewise 0.

Try this:

```
  BigDecimal b =  new BigDecimal( new BigInteger("2").pow(200) );
  BigDecimal one =  new BigDecimal(1);
  BigDecimal quotient = one.divide(b);
  System.out.println(quotient);   //scientific notation. (140 significant digits) 
  System.out.println(quotient.toPlainString()); //regular notation with leading zeros
```

Comment: Big Decimal it is giving exponential value , how to avoid it

Comment: @Sumeet Use toPlainString() to avoid scientific notation. I edited my code to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

The result of 1/(2^200) is going to be extremely small, and definitely not an integer, so the zero result you are getting is "correct".

The answer is so small that even Java double (64 bit) will run out of precision. You may be able to coax BigDecimal to give the correct answer, but the performance will almost certainly be terrible.

Why do you need such precision? The number of atoms in the universe has been estimated at around 10^38, which I think is around 2^150. We can help better if we know what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try for float/Double in case you get result in decimal points.

Comment: float is single precision (32 bits) and double uses 64 bits to store the value and the exponent. Both of these will need to round the answer, which is why we are using BigDecimal.